# FileAssociationInfo And ProgramAssociationInfo

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-mobile-5.0, file-association

I'm developing a application for Windows Mobile using C#(.Net Compact Framework 3.5), but I need to associate my program with a file type. When I try to use FileAssociationInfo I'm getting this error: `The type or namespace name 'FileAssociationInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the zip file from [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/249856-System-File-Association/) containing the FileAssociation solution file and source code (it's the 'Download:' link at the top of the article).

Comment: I guess it's too much to hope that a Microsoft website link would still work after 12 years.